# How can i get the values of each object in List

Tags: c#, list, class, properties, generic-list

I'm building a project for my degree (for my school degree) and i've builded a list, a generic list to add objects and to work with them.

Hapeens that i also create inside my list class a new method to List the contents of list for all `<T>` objects

I would like to print each `<T>` parameter or value, for example if `<T>` is `<Cars>` i want to print Mark, Model, Year, Fuel, Color ...

I know also that is throught a propriety, and try to build a propriety to solve this, but, may something could be wrong in my code:

Inside my List classe i have this:

- an `T [] array;`
- Constructors

  //Constructores

  public GenericList()
          {
              myList = new T[MAXLENGTH];
              counter = 0;
          }

and more two methods to add, list, and also a propriety of `T[] array`:

```
 public T[] ObjectosEmLista
        {
            get { return myList; }
            set { myList = value; }
        }

        //public T ConsultaObjectoPorNome(string n)
        //{

        //}

        public T AddObject (T obj)
        {
            aux.Add(obj);
            return obj;
        }





        //Listagem
        public void List()
        {

            foreach (T t in myList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Marca {0} ", t);
            }


        }
```

And in main Class:

```
  GenericList<Auto> autos = new GenericList<Auto>();
  autos.AddObject(new Auto("89-FF-42", "Citroen", "C4 1.6HDI"));
  autos.AddObject(new Auto("19-89-LH", "Mercedes", "E230"));
  autos.AddObject(new Auto("75-FA-45", "Skoda", "Fabia"));
```

So, how i can print for each one, the plate mark and model. Please help me, it's important.

Comment: if your `Auto` is a class (not shown!), you can override `ToString()` so it prints whatever you want.  `ObjectosEmLista` doesnt seem to do anything that a plain old `List<Auto>` wouldnt do with less code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Foreach loop

```
foreach (Auto item in autos)
{
   /// here you will get every item in the list and can access item.properties
   print item.ModelName //, .each property.. 
   //or
   print item.ToString;
}
```

Comment: Do not work correctly. Error: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Projecto_LP2.GenericList<Projecto_LP2.Auto>' because 'Projecto_LP2.GenericList<Projecto_LP2.Auto>' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: If you want to be able to iterate through each element in your list then implement IEnumerable<T>, it is simple enough then yo can use foreach.